# JSHint: 'let' is available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6') or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz). Как в WebStorm включить поддержку синтаксиса ES6

Tags: webstorm

Вроде все включил.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А все равно ругается. Что за беда? Подскажите

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если `Alt`+`Enter` нажать когда курсор возле `let` находится, то WebStorm предложит что-нибудь сделать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам нужно настроить JSHint, чтобы он правильно воспринимал ES6 синтаксис. Сделать это можно с помощью опции `"esversion"` (http://jshint.com/docs/options/#esversion):

```
{
  "esversion": 6
}
```

Если вы не используете `.jshintrc`, можно просто включить Ecmascript.next relaxing option:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Действительно! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вот [ссылка на аналогичный вопрос на англ. SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318895/vs-code-with-es6).

Там ответов побольше и подробнее. А вот, что мне помогло:

1. заходите в настройки расширения => settings.json
2. добавляете `"jshint.options": { "esversion": 6 }` и не забудьте добавить запятую на предыдущую строчку

Answer (score 0):

Создай файл с названием .jshintrc
в нем пишем

```json
{
    "camelcase" : true,
    "indent": 2,
    "undef": true,
    "quotmark": false,
    "maxlen": 120,
    "trailing": true,
    "curly": true,
    "strict": false,
    "browser": true,
    "devel": true,
    "jquery": true,
    "esversion": 9,
    "node": true
}
```

И сохраняем в папке где находится твоя работа
это настройка JsHInt-a для ES6